# Timed execution of a function

Tags: python

I need to execute a function on python on intervals of one minute repeatedly. There is another alternative to the "Busy Waith" method. Maybe some like a timer that wake up every minute.

Comment: Threading with sleep perhaps?

Comment: Do you need to do other things in the meantime?

Answer (score 3):

The best I can tell you is importing time and using 
     time.sleep(60)

Comment: I think that's the best option anyone can tell

Comment: Ok, thanks i will use it.